# I don't understand why this graph is a sine function.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My book said that a cosine curve has a y-intercept at one of the high or low points while a sine curve has one that's in the middle curve. The y-intercept on this curve is at the high point isn't it? So, why isn't it a cosine curve?

[image]

Comment: Remind that you can translate graph of function.

Comment: Why is Your graph unclear.

Comment: the simplest way in this test task is to play with max/min values

Comment: This graph cannot correspond to any of the four options given. In every case, $g(0)<0$.

Comment: Unfortunately the graph is very misleading and I would say this is simply a wrong question. Using that the maximum is at 1 and the minimum is at -3, and the period is 120 degrees, the only option would be (a). However, the curve is not aligned with the indicated  $x$-axis labels and hence none of the answers is correct. I presume they would like you to answer (a) though.

Comment: I think the book made a typo.  That happens.  But describing a "sine curve" and "cosine curve" while considering vertical shifts (adding or subtracting a constant outside the sin/cos function) without considering horizontal shifts (adding or subtracting a constant *inside* the sin/cos function) is in my opinion unforgivable.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this question deserved downvotes. It is not OP's fault that people publish textbooks containing egregious errors. It is reasonable for a student to tend to defer to a textbook as an authority (it's hard to learn while constantly doubting everything), and also reasonable to seek clarification from third parties (such as us) when accepting the textbook's authority seems to lead to contradictions. A student who could be expected to recognize and confidently analyze the error in the book should be taking a more advanced course.

Comment: I agree completely with @DavidK that this question does not deserve downvotes.  The student is confused by something in the textbook.  It turns out that the textbook is wrong!  That's not *at all* the student's fault and it is absolutely reasonable to ask for clarification in this case.

Answer (score 2):

*"My book said that a cosine curve has a y-intercept at one of the high or low points while a sine curve has one that's in the middle curve."*

Your book is wrong.  sine curves and cosine curves are the same thing as $\sin (kx) = \cos (kx - \frac {\pi}2) $.

But a function of the form $y = k\sin(jx) + c$ will have the $y$ intercept in the middle while a function of the form $y = k\cos(jx) +c$ will have the $y$ intercept in the extreme.

Likewise a function of the form $y = k\sin(jx - d) + c$ will have a value at $x = d$ of the middle while $y = k\cos(jx - d) + c$ will have a value at $x = d$ and the extreme.  (basically the entire graph will have been shifted to the right by $d$ units).

*" The y-intercept on this curve is at the high point isn't it?"*

Yes, you are correct.

*"So, why isn't it a cosine curve?"*

Since your book is wrong this isn't the right question. The right question is

*"So, why isn't this of the form $y=k\cos(jx)+ c$?"*

It is.  Your book is *still* wrong.

You have a truly crappy book.

======

the graph of $y = k \text{function}(jx + d) + c = k\text{function}(j(x + \frac dj))$ will be the same as the graph $y = \text{function}(x)$ with:

i) the graph will be shifted over to the left $d$ units.

ii) centering at $x = -d$ the graph will be made $j$ times thinner.

iii) centering at $y = 0$ the graph will be stretch $k$ times larger.

iv) the graph will be shifted up $c$ units.

(Alternatively i) and ii) can be altered that is is made thinner centered at $x = 0$ and shifted to the left by $\frac dj$ units$.)

Using this, we know that because $\cos (x) = \sin (x + 90^{\circ})$, the have the same graph but shifted to the right by $90^{\circ}$.  (Which is just far enough to shift the $y$-intecept from being in the middle $(\sin (0) = 0)$ to the highest value ($\sin (0 + 90^{\circ}) = 1$).)

======

A correct description of that graph could be any one of the following:

a) $y = 2\cos (3x) - 1$

b) $y = 2\sin (3x + 90) -1$

c) $y = 2\sin (3(x+30)) - 1$

d) $y = 2\sin (3(x - 90)) - 1$.

Comment: I usually avoid "+1" remarks, but I wish I could upvote this answer more than once for "truly crappy book." I am amazed sometimes at what abominably misconceived exercises some lower-level textbooks present--I even saw one here once that was updated in several titles/editions by the same author, who never fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

None of the given options match the graph shown, as $\sin(0)=0$ implies that $g(0)$ is either $-1$, $-2$, or $-3$ depending on which answer choice you investigate. So either the question is in error, or there is information relevant to the question that doesn't appear in the picture.

However, it is possible to use sine to define that curve, but it would have to be shifted horizontally. For instance, $\cos(x) = \sin(x+90^\circ)$. It is likely that you will see these horizontal translations in the future.